# How to auto power on windows laptop when lid is opened from shutdown state just like hibernation state?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, bios, uefi

It has been observed that most laptops power back on by themselves upon reopening the lid if they were in hibernation mode.

However, this behavior is not replicated when the laptop was in full shut down state. After a shutdown, closing the lid, and reopening it after some time, the laptop does not power on by itself.

Why the laptop powers on by itself in the case of hibernation? There must be some flag or setting configured on the system for this to happen.

We are now interested in finding a solution that would allow the laptop to power on by itself after a shutdown, similar to the behavior observed in hibernation. Is it possible to manually set flags or configure the settings (manually or using scripts or command line or PowerShell etc.) in general to get this behavior?

Comment: What is the exact goal of such a solution? Why doesn't hibernation work for you while shutdown does? XY problem IMO.

Comment: The is only 1 OFF state and numerous possibilities for "mostly off".  @OP - which do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it appears from other answers, for most laptops in general, the solution to this problem does not seem to exist as of current. Most answers and comments mentioned that it might not be possible to auto power on the laptop from full shutdown state upon opening the lid.

However, during my research process, I did encounter some laptop models which solve this problem using sensor which can indeed power on the device from full shutdown state. For example, Lenovo implies it has "Flip to Boot" or "Flip to Start" feature on some models (screenshot as proof).

[image]

Hence, in general, unless an actual script or program is presented as a proof that this problem can be solved without extra sensors, it can be concluded that there doesn't exist purely software-based solution (program/script/commands) to solve the problem.

#### Thoughts

Running `powercfg -a` command gave following output:

```
C:\Users\admin>powercfg -a
The following sleep states are available on this system:
    Standby (S0 Low Power Idle) Network Connected
    Hibernate
    Fast Startup
```

Then, Windows Copilot mentioned that:

```
In Hibernation mode, the CPU is powered off. The system saves its state to the hard disk and then powers down completely. When you start the system again, it reads the saved state from the disk and returns to its previous state. This allows the system to conserve power while preserving the system’s state.
```

If the CPU is also fully powered off (including RAM) during hibernation, then intuition tells that the command/information to auto power on upon lifting the lid must exist in some other hardware component. If so, then why is it not possible to set that command/information during the full shutdown as well? After all, from pure software/OS perspective, only difference between hibernation vs full shutdown seems to be that hibernation saves the current software state to secondary storage and restores while the other doesn't save and restore the working state.

Answer (score 1):

When hibernated the laptop is not really fully off.
It is a very deep sleep state, while some parts remains active that can monitor the lid-state and can take action (based on the preferences set by the user) depending on the state of the lid.

When it is shutdown it is really off (except for the real-time clock circuitry that always keeps running).
The only way to start it is by pressing the on/off button or (in some models) by a real-time clock based timer set via Bios/UEFI.
As John also mentioned, when it is off, the laptop has no way of knowing whether the lid is opened to start the laptop or to do maintenance on the laptop (or any other reason to play with the lid other than starting the laptop).
Even worse: Many laptops with an external monitor attached can be operated with the lid closed. In that case the user will NOT open it to start the laptop at all.
And there is the (very common) situation that the laptop can be shutdown while the lid was open and the user closed the lid later.

A laptop manufacturer would have to add quite a bit of circuitry and logic (and a means for the user to configure it to his desires) to the basic hardware/bios design to make this a useful feature. A lot of effort (cost) for a very small number of users that would potentially be interested in such a feature.
I am not aware of any laptop that has this.

So to answer the actual question: Can we change the behavior?
In general: No.
The behavior of the laptop when it is OFF is totally determined by the hardware/bios design and can not be altered/configured by the user in any way.
(Except for setting the real-time clock wake-up timer if this available.)

Comment: This answer is factually incorrect. when a computer with hybrid shutdown (windows 8.1 and up) is shutdown, all programs are closed, all wakeup events are suspended and the computer is then placed into hibernation. The fact that wake up events are suspended is the answer to this question.

Comment: Lenovo ideapad series mostly have this feature on by default. I have one but found this feature very annoying and turned it off in the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

> After a [full] shutdown, closing the lid, and reopening it after some
> time, the laptop does not power on by itself.

Entirely normal behavior for a full shutdown.

One needs to be able to open a laptop to clean or service it. So by design, laptops do not power on when the lid is opened.

If you wish to circumvent this behavior, you would most likely need to adjust the BIOS (UEFI) code. It is not an operating system issue because various operating systems can be installed.

It may also require extra hardware / electronics in the laptop.

Hibernation itself is tied in with BIOS  (and the operating system power drivers).

This is certainly the case for the vast majority of laptops and any I have seen.

Comment: This is not true. the reason it doesn't work, is because with hybrid shutdown, the wakeup timers are suspended to prevent the computer from accidentally turning on. Not sure if it is possible for a user to change the hybrid shutdown to allow for wake-events, but it is definitely possible to simulate the power off with wake timers enabled using some scripting or programming.

Comment: To the latter part of your comment, I do not think the scripting result would be true full shut down. I am fairly sure of this. Correct  - one may simulate it, but the question was full power off shutdown.

Comment: For a full power state where hybrid shutdown is disabled, then it is indeed not possible, and not to simulate either. However, Hybrid shutdown is enabled by default, and most people don't even know this exists. When they turn off a computer completely, for them it is fully shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

When Hybrid shutdown is turned on (default behavior) and you are using at least Windows 8.1, when turning off the computer, the user is being logged out, the wake timers are suspended and then the compouter is placed into hibernation. To the user, it will appear that the computer is fully shutdown, but technically the system is in hibernation.

The rest of this answer will assume that you have not turned off hybrid shutdown, as almost no one would do this.

It is the suspension of the wake timers that prevents the laptop from turning on when you open the lid.

The easiest way for you to simulate what you want is by changing the default shutdown method to just log off, and after that, simply close the lid.

If you then open the lid again, you get the logon screen, and after logging in, you get a fresh start in the very same way as if you had shutdown the computer.

It may be that the computer remains on for a while on the login screen, but in a sleep mode before going into hibernation. The benefit of this is that it will resume quicker if you open the lid again.

Alternatively, it may be even better to just use hibernation instead of logging out. That way, you continue right where you left off.

The only reason to actually log off, is to prevent anyone from using your laptop after you're done with it. This can also be prevented by simply having the setting: Always show sign-in screen when coming out of hibernation.